# Is there a way to return the same instance of a class population?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Stuft:
    population = {}  # class variable
    def __init(self, atr1, atr2):
        self.atr1 = atr1
        self.atr2 = atr2
        Stuft.population[(atr1, atr2)] = self  # store instance in population variable
```

and when I create an instance `cat = Stuft("meow", "paw")`, the instance got stored in `Stuft.population` as expected. The thing is at later time I might want to get to the same instance by calling `tiger = Stuft("meow", "paw")` so that `tiger` and `cat` point to the same instance and `tiger is cat` returns `True` because I dont want to create another instance with the same artributes. How do I do this in `Stuft` using `atr1` and `atr2` as reference point? Is there a dunder for this ?.

Comment: You can copy `cat` instance to `tiger`(tiger= cat). If that's not the case then probably you need to share expected sample in ua Q.

Answer (score 3):

You do this [with `__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) instead of `__init__`; `__init__` initializes a variable created for you, while `__new__` can choose to return an existing variable:

```
class Stuft:
    population = {}  # class variable
    def __new__(cls, atr1, atr2):
        try:
            self = cls.population[atr1, atr2]  # Try to get existing copy
        except KeyError:
            self = super().__new__(cls)        # Nothing in cache, make new instance
            self.atr1 = atr1                   # Initialize it
            self.atr2 = atr2
            cls.population[atr1, atr2] = self  # store instance in population variable
        return self                            # Must return an instance (unlike __init__)
```